# how to stop append same data from ajax call for mysql cause setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I made a simple chat application and everything is working fine,
but please let me know how to stop appending same data like,
looping in ajax call from setInterval. This is my code

```
setInterval(function() {
    get_ajax_msg(); 
}, 5000);

function get_ajax_msg(){
    //AJAX CALL//   
    $.ajax({
        url: "msg.php",
        data:'act=check&id='+call_id+'&fid='+call_fid,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
            if(data !=""){
                $('#ctlist').append(data);
            }
        }
    });
    //END AJAX CALL//
}
```

php code

```
$msg_id= $_POST['id'];
$runmsg = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chat_msg WHERE pid=". $msg_id ." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");

while ($mymsg = $db->fetch_array($runmsg)) {
    echo $mymsg['msg'];
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: get message for chat box

Comment: simple: don't get ALL the messages. only get the messages since the last time you asked for an update. that means you need to do `where date > $last_request`-type stuff.

Comment: can anybody give sample code for this?i really struck on this

Comment: Does there any primary key for chat_msg table with auto incremental?

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach without altering most of your code logic, store the ids of messages that are appended and then append only those ids that are not in the list. Its not the most not the most efficient way, but its the least change to your original code. (Note, I use underscore for iterating the array, you may use something else):

```
var oldIds = {};
setInterval(function() {
    get_ajax_msg(); 
}, 5000);

function get_ajax_msg(){
    //AJAX CALL//   
    $.ajax({
        url: "msg.php",
        data:'act=check&id='+call_id+'&fid='+call_fid,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
            if(data !=""){
                // iterate over each item in the returned array
                _.each(data, function(item){
                     // if item id is not present in the known list then  
                     if(_.isUndefined(oldIds[item.pid])){
                         // mark it as present
                         oldIds[item.pid] = true;
                         // append that item to the element
                         $('#ctlist').append(item);
                     }
                });

            }
        }
    });
    //END AJAX CALL//
}
```

Ofc, in ideal world, you would like to alter the parameters of your request to the server, to send you only new messages, unless your old messages may change or something could be inserted in between.

Answer (score 0):

You need many safeguard if you will follow this way:
1- first you need to track the last received message id to start from the next one 
2- Only call ajax again after the last again ends as there code be a delay in a request that makes the message order is not correct
3- Get all new messages not one by one

JS CODE:

```
var last_id = 0;
function get_ajax_msg(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "msg.php",
        data:'act=check&id='+call_id+'&fid='+call_fid+'&last_id='+last_id,
        type: "POST",
            success: function(data) { 
                if(data !=""){
                    // parse the json data
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    last_id = data["last_id"];
                    // Add the list of comments
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < data["msg"]; i++)
                        $('#ctlist').append(data["msg"][i]+"<br>");
                }
                // Run again after finishing the first request
                setTimeout(function() {
                    get_ajax_msg();     
                }, 5000);
            }
    });
}
// Run it for the fisrt time
get_ajax_msg();
```

PHP CODE:

```
$msg_id= $_POST['id'];
$last_id = intval($_POST['last_id']);
// Get all new comments
$runmsg = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chat_msg WHERE pid=". $msg_id ." and `id` > '$last_id' ORDER BY date DESC");
$info = [];
while ($mymsg = $db->fetch_array($runmsg))
{
    // append to the array of messages
    $info[] = $mymsg['msg'];
    // set the last used id
    $last_id = $mymsg["id"];
}

echo json_encode({"msg": $info, "last_id": $last_id});
```